# MongoDB $geoWithin not working

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection in mongodb on which I am running GeoWithin for circle query to filter the data but it is behaving weird .

Document of collection is

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3),
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2014-11-05T06:14:49.497Z"),
    "lastUpdatedBy" : NumberLong(4),
    "name" : "test",
    "user" : NumberLong(4),
    "visibility" : true,
    "visibleTo" : "EveryOne",
    "visiblityCity" : [
        {
            "country" : "United States",
            "countryCode" : "US",
            "location" : {
                "lat" : 40.7127837,
                "long" : -74.00594130000002
            },
            "name" : "New York",
            "state" : "New York"
        }
    ],
    "visiblityCountry" : [
        {
            "countryCode" : "US",
            "location" : {
                "lat" : 40.7127837,
                "long" : -74.00594130000002
            },
            "name" : "United States"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created 2d index on visiblityCity.location

```
db.<collection name>.ensureIndex( {"visiblityCity.location" : "2d" })
```

The db..getIndexes(); result is as follow

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mopi.survey",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "visiblityCity.location" : "2d"
        },
        "ns" : "mopi.survey",
        "name" : "visiblityCity.location_2d"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "visiblityCity.location" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "ns" : "mopi.survey",
        "name" : "visiblityCity.location_2dsphere"
    }
]
```

Now when I am running command

> db.survey.find({"visiblityCity.location": {"$geoWithin": {"$center" : [[84.7274,25.7848], 0.14]} } }).count();
>       0

and when I am running

> db.survey.find({"visiblityCity.location": {"$geoWithin": {"$center" : [[84.7274,25.7848], 85]} } }).count();
>   2

Since 85 and 0.14 is the radian value . There must be one result I must get for Radian value 0.14 but I am getting 0 results .

The result count  I get for radian 85 is 2 , both documents have distance 85km and 1349 km respectively . And where as when I am converting distances in radian then I get radian value much smaller than 85.

Comment: Have you tried geoNear using GeoJSON rather than legacy coordinates, or do you have an older version of MongoDB?

Comment: You also have both "2d" and "2dsphere" indexes on the same field. This is not good in general. I think the ordering of keys is messing with this. BSON keys are considered to preserve order. Arrays are preferred since to all languages "hash" objects with ordered keys. As @JohnBarça says, GeoJSON is the better option for modelling this unless you have a "legacy" version restriction otherwise.

Comment: I was using [longitude,latitude] in geoWithin , when I change it to [latitude,longitude] , it worked for me .